# Why is oauth2client run_flow giving an Argparse error?

Tags: python-2.7, argparse, oauth2client

I have a python (2.7) program that uses oauth2client to access google drive. I'm trying to get my initial credentials file. I'm using this:

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run_flow


    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    credentials = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = os.path.join(credential_path, 'client_secret.json'
    flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=SCOPE)
    http = httplib2.Http()
    credentials = run_flow(flow, store, http=http)
```

However, I am getting what appears to be an Argparser usage error?

```
usage: responseratedash2.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                            [--noauth_local_webserver]
                            [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                            [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
responseratedash2.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -r 2341 -t
```

responseratedash2.py is the name of my program, and -r 2341 -t are valid arguments for that program. But this error is happening in the `run_flow` line...

Why is this happening?

(ETA: Explaining how I'm using oauth2client, the flow functions are both from that library.)

Comment: It appears tat `responseratedash2` has its own parser, and is using the same `sys.argv` that your own code is using.  So while the `-r` may be valid for your code, it isn't valid for that parser.  You can see what arguments it recognizes, all those login values.

Comment: Sure, but why is any library that lots of people use using sys.argv??? How do I make it not assume that the surrounding program doesn't have it's own arguments?

Comment: Oh, and responseratedash2 is the name of my program. The usage listed is **NOT** the correct usage for responseratedash2. -r and -t are fire for responseratedash2.

Comment: How is `oauth2client` supposed to get those arguments?  Is your own code ok with those?  Is it prepared to pass them on to a relevant module or function. I've seen an issue like this before, but don't recall the solution.  I suspect `oautho2client` (or what ever it's called) is meant to be called as a script, not as an embedded module.  You don't show anything about how you invoke it.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46737536/unrecognized-arguments-using-oauth2-and-google-apis

Comment: and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890146/how-to-get-google-analytics-credentials-without-gflags-using-run-flow-instea and https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#command-line-tools

Comment: I would assume that a library gets arguments via function parameters not sys.argv.

Comment: All usage of oauth2client I've seen have been as library,  but assuming command line args for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

The answer appears to be, for some reason, oauth2client.tools assumes that you're running it with command line arguments. There is probably a good reason for this for the original use-case, but it looks really weird for mine.

The solution is that `run_flow` takes a `flags` argument, which can be set up  via:

```
flags=oauth2client.tools.argparser.parse_args(args=[])
```

which zeros that out...

Comment: Yes, the first thing the function code does is check if `flags is None`, in which case it sets it with `flags=argparser.parse_args()`.  I'd suggest looking at the `flags` variable that your code ran.  Running `parse_args` with `[]` is equivalent to running the script without any commandline values.

Comment: My point is that running parse_args with [] is THE ONLY WAY to run the library function as if it has no commandline args... (I tried passing [] as flags, to run_flow and it didn't appear to work...)

Comment: Right, `flags` is supposed to be a `argparse.Namespace` with the right attributes.  Or a functional equivalent.  The `Namespace` class isn't complicated.  It's just looking for the 3 documented attributes.  Using `args=[]` produces flags with the documented defaults.